# SaltStack extending another pillar

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using SaltStack, and I'm trying to re-use the values of a nested dictionary from one Pillar config in another one. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

Say I have `pillar/app/common.sls` which has the following items:

```
app:
  lookup:
    custom1: 'change the default'
    custom2: 'change the default'
  service1:
    value1: 'foo'
    value2: 'bar'
    list1:
      - apple
      - banana
    value3: 'xen'
```

What I'm aiming for is to have a new service (and the YAML key would be `service2`) on the same machine, but set up in such a way so that I'm not writing values twice (keep it DRY!). I would also like to override the value of one of the parameters. Essentially, I'm trying to extend one pillar into another.

The ***end result*** would be:

```
app:
  lookup:
    custom1: 'change the default'
    custom2: 'change the default'
  service1:
    value1: 'foo'
    value2: 'bar'
    list1:
      - apple
      - banana
    value3: 'xen'
  service2:
    value1: 'foo'
    value2: 'bar'
    list1:
      - apple
      - banana
    value3: 'future'
```

I've tried the following with a `pillar/app/someserver.sls`:

```
{% import_yaml "app/common.sls" as common %}

app:
  service2:
    {{ common.app.service1 }}
    value3: 'future'
```

What I've found is `{{ common.app.service1 }}` successfully renders, but it doesn't like the additional `value3: 'future'`, which is my attempt to override `value3` which comes from `common.sls`.

I'm using Salt 2016.11.4 on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.2. Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `common.app.service1` variable is nothing more than a common Python dict, you *should*  be able to modify it using `update`. After that, you can use Jinja's `yaml` filter to render it into the new pillar:

```
{% import_yaml "app/common.sls" as common %}
{% set service2 = common.app.service1.copy() %}
{% do service2.update({value3: 'future'}) %}

app:
  service2: {{ service2 | yaml }}
```